# Use switch and "in" in MS-Access Select Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

let's say I have two tables, where the first one contains my data:

| Automatic | Manual |
| --- | --- |
| X1 | X1 |
| Y | Y27 |

and a lookup table

| Lookup |
| --- |
| X1 |
| Y27 |
| ... |

I want to select the value from the first table, IF it is contained in the lookup table.
So for the second row, it should take the value Y27, because Y ist not in the lookup table.

I tried it with this query:

```sql
Select 
Switch(
       Automatic in (SELECT Lookup FROM LookupTable), Automatic,
       True, Manual,
      ) AS ValidEntry
FROM Datatable;
```

My query as text: Check if the value from "Automatic" is inside the lookup table, if yes -> take the value, if not, take the value from the other column "manual" and return an entry named "ValidEntry".

Answer (score 0):

Use a INNER JOIN, it should be much faster.

```
select somedata from table1 t  
inner join lookupTbl l on l.lookupfield = t.automatic
```

With IN clause:

```
select somedata from table1 t  
WHERE t.automatic IN (select lookupfield FROM lookupTbl)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you approach Patrick, but unfortunately those solutions don't take in account the other column, it just checks if the value from one column is apparent in the lookup table. I have to combine the steps, so I can validate 2 columns at the same time against the other table and return just 1 value, if valid.

Comment: @SHA-256  Then use a LEFT JOIN and check for NULLs. It will still be much more  efficient than a Lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
SELECT NZ( LookupTableAutomatic.Lookup, LookupTableManual.Lookup) AS Lookup
FROM (LookupTable AS LookupTableManual INNER JOIN DataTable  
ON LookupTableManual.Lookup = DataTable.Manual) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN LookupTable AS LookupTableAutomatic ON LookupTableAutomatic.Lookup = DataTable.Automatic;
```

By way of explanation the NZ Function returns the first parameter if it is not null, otherwise it takes the second. The lookup table is joined twice: the Manual Lookup is an INNER JOIN, as I am assuming that there will always be a fallback value, whereas the Automatic lookup is joined as an OUTER JOIN, meaning that it returns NULL when the value is not matched.

Comment: FYI: Nz() is far from ideal in terms of performance. And if you have linked tables pointing to large tables on SQL Server or Oracle, it's a nightmare. See http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html

Comment: @Patrick Honorez afaik NZ is very little different to IIF when the types are text (as in this case). Secondly, if the OP is using linked tables to SQL Server or Oracle, then it would be massively more efficient to create the view on the linked server rather than within Access in which case COALESCE is the way to go.

Comment: Jonathan: you clearly did not read the article in the link. And by experience, I can guarantee the difference is HUGE between NZ and IIF for big tables linked to SQL Server. Using NZ will also prevent reading the query from Excel, whereas IIF will work.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez As a matter of fact I did read the article.  I particularly noted that 4 reasons were given for preferring IIF over NZ.  1) It avoids a function call; 2) You retain the intended data type: 3) The criteria are applied correctly; and 4)  The column sorts correctly.  To these 1) it is still using a function (IIF instead of NZ) 2) Irrelevant if the data type is text (as here) 3) What does this actually mean???  Not described at all - if it is suggesting that NZ doesn't work, this is palpably absurd.  4)  Same as 2) not true if the column was text anyway.  So not very cogent.